# Is Blender capable to edit 4K video yet (the year is June 2020)?

Tags: edit-mode, video

I downloaded a 4K demo video for testing video editing with Blender.
I have found questions & answers regarding Blender 4K video editing that are dated back in February 2017 (not recommended) and June 2019 (video sequencer so slow).
Will give it up if it is not doable.

Thank you.

Comment: Doable? Possibly. Advisable? Probably not. Blender is a wonderful 3d content creation app,  but an antiquated and clumsy video editing tool. In 2020 there are plenty of other programs avalable with more robust tools and way better performance ,some of them are free as well. If you use blender be prepared to be disappointed.

Comment: Try DaVinci Resolove free.